# mplfinance - add_artist raises AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'axes'

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I am using `mplfinance` to create a OHLC chart (stock prices)

This is implemented as a custom class as I need to add additional elements to the final chart

```
class CandlestickChart:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.fig, self.ax = mpf.plot(
            self.data,
            type="ohlc",
            volume=False,
            returnfig=True,
        )
```

I then have another function that

```
def add_swap_zone(self, swap_zone):
        zone_data = self.data.copy()
        zone_data["in_swap_zone"] = (zone_data.index >= swap_zone.x_left) & (
            zone_data.index <= swap_zone.x_right
        )
        zone_data["swap_zone_val"] = np.nan
        zone_data.loc[zone_data["in_swap_zone"], "swap_zone_val"] = swap_zone.y_down
        zone_data["swap_zone_val"].fillna(swap_zone.y_up, inplace=True)

        ap_swap_zone = mpf.make_addplot(
            zone_data["swap_zone_val"],
            type="bar",
            width=0.5,
            color=swap_zone.style.FILL_COLOUR,
            alpha=swap_zone.style.FILL_ALPHA,
            panel=0,
            secondary_y=False,
        )

        self.ax[0].add_artist(ap_swap_zone)
```

While the mechanics of the function may look complex, in essence I am using `mpf.make_addplot` to create a new plot, which then gets added to `self.ax[0]`

The error I receive is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/projects/charter/src/draw/demo/demo_plot.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/projects/charter/src/draw/demo/demo_plot.py", line 35, in main
    cs_chart.add_swap_zone(
  File "/Users/user/projects/charter/src/draw/plot.py", line 39, in add_swap_zone
    self.ax[0].add_artist(ap_swap_zone)
  File "/Users/user/projects/charter/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2219, in add_artist
    a.axes = self
    ^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'axes'
```

I have tried the below alternative ways to add the plot and still failed

1. `self.ax[list(self.ax.keys())[0]].add_artist(ap_swap_zone)`
2. `self.ax["0"].add_artist(ap_swap_zone)`

EDIT:
Revised code based on selected answer

```
class CandlestickChart:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.addplot_specs = []

    def add_swap_zone(self, swap_zone):
        zone_data = self.data.copy()
        zone_data["in_swap_zone"] = (zone_data.index >= swap_zone.x_left) & (
            zone_data.index <= swap_zone.x_right
        )
        zone_data["swap_zone_val"] = np.nan
        zone_data.loc[zone_data["in_swap_zone"], "swap_zone_val"] = swap_zone.y_down
        zone_data["swap_zone_val"].fillna(swap_zone.y_up, inplace=True)

        ap_swap_zone = mpf.make_addplot(
            zone_data["swap_zone_val"],
            type="bar",
            width=0.5,
            color=swap_zone.style.FILL_COLOUR,
            alpha=swap_zone.style.FILL_ALPHA,
            panel=0,
            secondary_y=False,
        )

        self.addplot_specs.append(ap_swap_zone)

    def plot(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = mpf.plot(
            self.data,
            type="ohlc",
            volume=False,
            returnfig=True,
            addplot=self.addplot_specs,
        )
        mpf.show()
```

Constructor initialises `self.addplot_specs[]` which is then appended with addplot specification in `add_swap_zone()`. The mpl.plot() passes addplot=self.addplot_specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While the mechanics of the function may look complex, in essence I am using mpf.make_addplot to create a new plot, which then gets added to self.ax[0]

Your problem is that `mpf.make_addplot()` does not return a matplotlib `Artist` object.

Rather, `mpf.make_addplot()` returns an "**`addplot` specification object**" which can then be passed into the `addplot=` kwarg of `mpf.plot()`

(alternatively one can also assign a `list` of such "`addplot` specification" objects to the `addplot=` kwarg).

You should rearrange you code accordingly to *first* build the list of one or more `make_addplot()` objects (inside your `CandlestickChart` object), and then call `mpf.plot()`.

Thus the `CandlestickChart` **constructor** should ***not*** call `mpf.plot()` but rather create a method on the class that will call `mpf.plot()` when you are ready.

(Or alternatively the constructor can call `mpf.plot()` but only if it has all of the addplot specification objects at the time of construction).

Let me know if that answers your question or if you need any additional information.

(P.S. Just fyi, the reason you are getting an error messsage about a `dict` is because, for the time being, the `addplot` specification object is a `dict`, however this is not always guaranteed to be the case.  It could be that some day in the future mplfinance will have a need to define its own class for the `addplot` specification object, which is why mplfinance users should *not* manipulate this `dict` on their own but rather only use `mpf.make_addplot()` to build it.)

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Just realised what I actually need is something like Rectangle of matplotlib. Essentially swap zone is a rectangle that needs to be painted over the candlestick chart. Will keep digging

Comment: if so, you may also want to [take at this answer here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/606#issuecomment-1508889948) (as well as the question above it, for context) as it may possibly be helpful also for your situation.

Comment: This is great. Will take a deeper dive into `matplotlib` . Seems like ax.patches and Rectangles would do the trick